# S3 method dispatch in data.table when using `by` clause

Tags: r, data.table

**Update:** it appears this is an issue with data.table version 1.9.4 and not the most recent version of the package (1.9.6 as of this writing).

I have a table which I read in via `fread` like so:

```
library(data.table)
library(bit64)
dt = fread('"x","y"\n2489751247,"a"\n2492940518,"b"\n2444706811,"a"\n2408767228,"b"')

:>              x y
:>  1: 2489751247 a
:>  2: 2492940518 b
:>  3: 2444706811 a
:>  4: 2408767228 b
```

and I want the sum of `x` conditional on `y`, but data.table gives the wrong answer:

```
dt[,.(total=sum(x)),by=y]

:>     y         total
:>  1: a 2.437946e-314
:>  2: b 2.421765e-314
```

without the courtesy of a warning message.  It turns out that x is of class integer64:

```
lapply(dt,class)

:>  $x
:>  [1] "integer64"
:>  $y
:>  [1] "character"
```

so I can do the s3 dispatch manually like so:

```
dt[,.(total=sum.integer64(x)),by=y]

:>     y      total
:>  1: a 4934458058
:>  2: b 4901707746
```

and for some reason using the class of x in the `j` clause causes data.table to give the 
correct answer:

```
dt[,.(total=sum(x),cls=class(x)),by=y]

:>     y      total       cls
:>  1: a 4934458058 integer64
:>  2: b 4901707746 integer64
```

which is weird.  Is there some way to tell `data.table` to use S3 methods without using the class explicitly?

Comment: What's your `data.table` version? Works fine for me on v1.9.6 with `sum(x)`.

Comment: Oh.  It appears I'm on, I'm on data.table version 1.9.4, which is the most up to date version that the RRO repo (`https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-08-27`) points to.  I updated from a cran mirror, which fixed the problem...

Comment: Glad to know. Please remember to post your `sessionInfo()` for these kinds of issues. It'd be best for you to answer the Q yourself and accept it so that it is useful for other users who might stumble upon the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular issue was specific to data.table version 1.9.4 and not the most recent version of the data.table package (1.9.6 as of this writing).  You can inspect your version of data.table via:

```
installed.packages()['data.table','Version']
```

and if it's less than `1.9.6` then you need to call `install.packages('data.table')`.  Note that if you are using a version of R provided by Revolution Analytics, you'll need to set the `repos` argment to [your favorite CRAN mirror](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) explicitly as their most up to date repo (as of this writing) has data.table version 1.9.4:

```
install.packages('data.table',repos="http://my.favorite.CRAN.mirror/")
```

Although I **very rarely** use the [.Rprofile.site](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html), I put these lines in the that file in on the machines i work with:

```
if( packageVersion("data.table") == package_version('1.9.4'))
    install.packages("data.table",lib=Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"),repos='http://my.favorite.CRAN.mirror')
```

Comment: `packageVersion("data.table")` is a nice one too

Comment: Thanks, @RS.  I was unaware of `packageVersion` -- that's a nice interface for comparing package versions!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else searching for this with a newer version of data.table, note that S3 method dispatch still does not always happen when using `by` -- apparently this is intentional out of considerations for speed. See https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3533

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23003930)